# How to throw exception if no data Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to throw exception if no data Laravel when I expect some values?

```
$roles = Auth::user()->roles()->get();
```

So, is it good idea to use:

```
if ($roles->count() == 0) {
   throw new \Exception('No data');
}
```

But what if `$roles` are null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
$roles = Auth::user()->roles();

if($roles->isNotEmpty()){
    $roles = $roles->get();
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections

Comment: I need to get not only first row, all rows

Comment: Are you looking for sth. like this?